# Mostrar el usuario logueado con Flutter y Supabase

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase

Trato de mostrar el usuario logueado, para esto utilizo una consulta que proviene de esta clase.

```
class DbService extends ChangeNotifier {
      final SupabaseClient _supabase = Supabase.instance.client;
      UserModel? userModel;
      
      Future<UserModel> getUserData() async {
        final userData = await _supabase
            .from(Constants.userTable)
            .select()
            .eq('id', _supabase.auth.currentUser!.id)
            .single();
        userModel = UserModel.fromJson(userData);
        return userModel!;
      }
      }
```

Aquí es donde mando a llamar el método `getUserData()` de la clase *DbService*. Lo que sucede es que el `LinearProgressIndicator()` se queda cargando y no me muestra nada: posiblemente la consulta obtiene un `null`.

```
Consumer<DbService>(builder: (context, dbServie, child) {
        return FutureBuilder(
            future: dbServie.getUserData(),

            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                UserModel user = snapshot.data!;

                return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Text(
                    user.name != '' ? user.name : "#${user.id}",
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                );
              }
              return const SizedBox(
                width: 60,
               child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
              );
            });
      }),
```

Comment: no te tira ninguno error luego de esto?  userModel = UserModel.fromJson(userData);  , hiciste debug o agregaste un log para ver si llega?

Comment: como dice @diegoveloper, intenta hacer un print del objeto o de uno de sus atributos para saber si está obteniendo datos de la consulta y luego actualiza tu pregunta para que puedas agregar más información y poder ayudarte

Comment: Hola muchachos, gracias por sus sugerencias, acabo de debugear y resulto que el problema venia de la clase user_model, declare variables con otro tipo de datos de los atributos de la tabla user, trabajo con supabase, problema resuelto, gracias